# Put $$ in dollar-quoted string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, syntax, escaping, dynamic-sql, quoting

I have a function in Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert(sql_insert text, sql_update text) 
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 EXECUTE sql_insert;
 RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
 EXECUTE sql_update; 
 RETURN 2;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION upsert(text, text) OWNER TO dce;
```

I usually use this query to call that function:

```
select upsert(
  $$INSERT INTO zz(a, b) VALUES (66, 'hahahaha')$$,
  $$UPDATE zz SET a=66, b='hahahaha' WHERE a=66$$
)
```

It works. Unfortunately, my query string cannot contain `$$`, like this:

```
select upsert(
  $$INSERT INTO zz(a, b) VALUES (66, 'ha$$hahaha')$$,
  $$UPDATE zz SET a=66, b='hahahaha' WHERE a=66$$
)
```

I have read [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html) Postgres documentation but still need assistance how to do it.

Answer (score 14):

Use different [dollar-quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) instead:

```
select upsert(
   $unique_token$INSERT INTO zz(a, b) VALUES (66, 'ha$$hahaha')$unique_token$,
   $unique_token2$UPDATE zz SET a=66, b='hahahaha' WHERE a=66$unique_token2$
   )
```

Each end has to match each start. The two pairs do not have to be distinct, but it's safest that way.

This still leaves a theoretical chance that the dollar-quote might be matched inside the string.

If you are building the query by hand, just check for `$` in the string.
If you are building the query from variables, use [`quote_literal(string)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) or [`quote_nullable(string)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)instead.

There is also the convenient [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function.

See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Aside: This form of dynamic SQL is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection. Anything of the sort should be for very private or very secure use only.

Comment: i building the query by variables.So, i think i would use quote_literal(). it's very usefull.

Comment: Just ran into a similar situation, a big 'Dankeschön' for your proposed solution(s)..

Comment: You may need to quote $$ in a dynamic sql statement within a function. In that case, use adapted $ quoting for the function, such as $Q$ instead of $$.
See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-development-tips.html