# Escaping single quotes in REDSHIFT SQL

Tags: sql, escaping, amazon-redshift, sql-insert, single-quotes

I've lots of string values containing single quotes which I need to insert to a column in REDSHIFT table. 
I used both `/'` and `''` to escape the single quote in INSERT statement.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO table_Temp
    VALUES ('1234', 'O\'Niel'), ('3456', 'O\'Brien')
```

I also used '' instead of \' but it keeps giving me error that "VALUES list must of same length" i.e. no: of arguments for each record >2.

Can you let know how to have this issue resolved?

Answer (score 21):

The standard in SQL is double single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO table_Temp (col1, col2)  -- include the column names
    VALUES ('1234', 'O''Niel'), ('3456', 'O''Brien');
```

You should also include the column names corresponding to the values being inserted.  That is probably the cause of your second error.

Comment: The table only has 2 columns and both are VAR CHAR. I've tried with double single quotes as well. It's not working.

Comment: @stack_pointerisEXTINCT . . . This is quite strange.  Are you sure you are using the "simple" single quote and not some fancier character?

Comment: I noticed a different problem was there because of commas used within the names and it was a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may depend on your environment. I'm using Periscope Data's redshift SQL editor, and `\` worked as an escape character. `''` and `\\` did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CHR(39) and concat the strings. Your name would look like below:

```
  ('O' || CHR(39)||'Brian')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem , I was needing send a kind of JSON structure to then decode it into my query but there was a program receiving my string and this program was escaping my escapes, so the query fails, finally I found this :
[Put $$ in dollar-quoted string in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272007/put-in-dollar-quoted-string-in-postgresql)
mentioning quote_literal(42.5)
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER
This resolves my issue . an example 
String is
'LocalTime={US/Central}; NumDays={1}; NumRows={3}; F_ID={[Apple, Orange, Bannana]}'

```
Select  
   Param, value , replace(quote_literal(replace(replace(Value,'[',''),']','')),',',quote_literal(',')) ValueList 
    FROM (
    select 
        SPLIT_PART(split,'=',1) as Param,
        replace( replace(SPLIT_PART(split,'=',2),'{',''),'}','') as Value
    FROM 
    (
        select 
            trim(split_part(freeform.txt, ';', number.n)) as split 
        from 
        (   select 
            'LocalTime={US/Central}; NumDays={1}; NumRows={3}; F_ID={[Apple, Orange, Bannana]}' as txt
        ) freeform,
        (   select 1 as n union all
            select 2 union all
            select 3 union all
            select 4 union all
            select 5 union all
            select 6 union all
            select 7 union all
            select 8 union all
            select 9 union all
            select 10
        ) number
        where split <> ''
    ) as MY_TMP
    ) as valuePart
```

Answer (score 0):

double single quotes worked in my use case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

use `\\'` to escape `'`

```
s = s.replace("'", "\\'")
```

Comment: This is not something you can do in Redshift.